# Install libapache2-mod-fastcgi to Debian 8 Jessie

Tags: linux, debian, apache-http-server, fastcgi

For supporting FastCGI feature into Apache web-server need to install libapache2-mod-fastcgi system package. The package is unavailable in default sources.
How to install this package into Debian 8 Jessie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the non-free repository is enabled by inspecting `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

If non-free is not included then modify the file so that it does.

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian  main non-free
```

Update your system.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You can now install the package :

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi
```

Comment: @karavanjo, don't do this; install `libapache2-mod-fcgid` instead (which is available in Debian proper). It's API-compatible with `-fastcgi`, has no licensing problems and has better support in Debian.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative library is `libapache2-mod-fastcgi` (https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/).

`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi`

As stated in the comments by @kostix